# How can I parse an array as body in AWS API Gateway WebSocket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

I'm setting up a websocket server with AWS API Gateway where IoT devices not developed by me connect to and start interacting. These devices implement a protocol based on Websocket that requires the body to have the following format:

```
[
    2,
    "<RequestID>",
    "<Action>",
    {
        "parameter1": "value1",
        "parameter2": "value2",
        "parameter3": "value3"
    }
]
```

Based on the value of `Action` (third element in the array above) I need to call the appropriate Lambda function that'll handle the message with the parameters provided, so I wanted to implement in API Gateway a websocket selection expression (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api-selection-expressions.html) that gets that element from the array, but the official documentation does not mention anything about array bodies.

I guess the alternative is that I call always a Lambda that implements this evaluation and then calls the appropriate Lambda, but I wanted to optimize the costs and reduce the most I can the function calls by calling directly the right function.

Do you know if it is possible to do this?

I tried using both `$request.body[2]` that throws an error, and `$request.body.2` that does not work (I guess it looks for a property with key equal to "2" inside the body object).

Comment: Any solution so far? I am facing the same issue. The protocol my app has to implement sends an array as the body.

Comment: Nope, nothing so far. I went for the "Lambda that proxies to other Lambda functions" solution. It's been up for a couple of week and it's working fine, so I moved to other stuff to implement. I suggest you to follow the same procedure and create a Lambda function that performs the body validation and calls the right Lambda function handler, so you can put all the common logic inside the first Lambda. Only downside is that you have twice the execution count, so it could be more expensive.

Comment: Well darn. We are building a messaging system and every cpu cycle counts. This seems like a bug that should be addressed. ```{"request":{"body": [ "my", "items"]}}``` is valid JSON and should be accepted IMO.

Comment: Any solution for this? We are also using what appears to be OCPP requests.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using `$request.body.[0]` works. I did not know that this was a valid JSON expression. Just tested in console and route was picked up. The only issue is that if `$request.body.[0] == int()` it won't match a route that is named by that integer. I assume that when AWS tests against the route expression the left side of that evaluation is an integer (JSON number) and the right side is a string.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are dealing with OCPP messages. We are able to get this working with the Serverless framework. If you look at a standard message format:

```
[2, 48799347859454, "BootNotification", {"Test": "Test"}]
```

We are able to route the message by the action (i.e. BootNotification).

In our `serverless.yml` file, we specified the following in our provider:

```
  websocketsApiName: test-websocket-api
  websocketsApiRouteSelectionExpression: $request.body.[2]
```

and then the route function looks like:

```
  BootNotificationHandler:
    name: bootnotification
    handler: bootNotification.handler
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: BootNotification
```